# Xamarin implementation of ByteBuffer.Get wrong?

Tags: android, xamarin, bytebuffer

Here's a sample function that fills a small ByteBuffer, and then that reads it into a large byte array:

```
// Allocate the two buffers once for all.
const int byteBufferSize = 20;
var byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.Allocate(byteBufferSize);
/* var byteBufferArray = new byte[byteBufferSize];
var byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.Wrap(byteBufferArray);*/
var bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024];
var bytesPos = 0;

for (;;)
{
    // Put byteBuffer in "write" mode.
    byteBuffer.Clear();

    // Write a few bytes in byteBuffer.
    for (var i = 0; i < byteBufferSize; ++i)
        byteBuffer.Put(0);

    // Put byteBuffer in "read" mode.
    byteBuffer.Flip();

    // Read the written bytes from byteBuffer.
    // DEEP BELOW, THIS CALL UNEXPECTEDLY CAUSES A NASTY ALLOCATION OF ABOUT bytes.length BYTES!
    byteBuffer.Get(bytes, bytesPos, byteBufferSize);

    bytesPos += byteBufferSize;

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

When I run this code on Nexus 5 running Android 5.0, it seems to be fine. But when I run it on a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3, every time ByteBuffer.Get gets called, it seems a buffer of size bytes.length (1 Mo here) gets allocated somewhere inside ByteBuffer.Get, and after a short while the logs look like:

```
05-15 09:50:28.519: D/dalvikvm(23104): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 48% free 10250K/19624K, paused 49ms, total 49ms
05-15 09:50:29.580: D/dalvikvm(23104): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 48% free 10250K/19624K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
05-15 09:50:30.622: D/dalvikvm(23104): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 48% free 10250K/19624K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
05-15 09:50:31.673: D/dalvikvm(23104): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 48% free 10250K/19624K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
05-15 09:50:32.724: D/dalvikvm(23104): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1024K, 48% free 10250K/19624K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
...
```

Is it something that I do with the ByteBuffer object or it there something wrong with ByteBuffer.Get in Xamarin? Note that I did test the same code in a native Android Java app the code ran as expected, i.e. without the crazy allocations triggered by ByteBuffer.Get.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this page first while researching this issue, I have now filed an enhancement request that discusses the underlying causes of this problem as well some possible workarounds:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31260